# Iterate over multiple JSONs instead of just one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a bit of jQuery that iterates through some JSON (specifically a Google Calendar feed) and prints out a list item for each event in the calendar. The code looks like this:

```
// URL for some Google Calendar data
// (if this link should go down, any gcal feed URL should work just the same)
var gcalUrl = "http://mikeclaffey.com/sandbox/gcal-embed/example-json-data.js";

// Get list of upcoming events formatted in JSON
$.getJSON(gcalUrl, function(data){

    // Parse and render each event
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item){

        // Render the event
        $("#gcal-events li").last().after( "<li>" + item.title.$t + "</li>" );
    });
});
```

I am trying to adapt the code so that it can combine JSON from multiple URLs, but I'm having trouble combining the JSON data into one object. I tried iterating through an array of JSON URLs and combining all the data into one object, but it doesn't seem to create a usable object. Here's my code:

```
var gcalUrls = ["http://mikeclaffey.com/sandbox/gcal-embed/example-json-data.js"];
var allData = {};

// Iterate through the array of Google Calendar feed URLs
$.each(gcalUrls, function(i, url) {

    // Download each feed
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){

        // Add this feed's data to allData
        $.extend(true, allData, data);
    });
});

// Parse and render each event
$.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item){

    // Render the event
    $("#gcal-events li").last().after( "<li>" + item.title.$t + "</li>" );
});
```

This code fails to print out anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the Chrome debugging tools? You can pause execution and step through your code as it's executing, line by line. I think the problem will become much clearer if you do.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because of the async nature of ajax.

You can use $.when() to solve it like

```
var gcalUrls = ["http://mikeclaffey.com/sandbox/gcal-embed/example-json-data.js"];
var allData = {};

// Iterate through the array of Google Calendar feed URLs
var promises = $.map(gcalUrls, function (i, url) {

    // Download each feed
    return $.getJSON(url);
});

$.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
    // Parse and render each event
    $.each(arguments, function (i, arg) {
        // Parse and render each event
        $.each(arg[0].feed.entry, function (i, item) {

            // Render the event
            $("#gcal-events li").last().after("<li>" + item.title.$t + "</li>");
        });
    });
})
```